# What's the name of the screwdriver that will open up an iPhone 4?

Tags: iphone, hardware

I realize that opening up the iPhone can void the warranty, it's already out of warranty, so I'm okay with that. I was wondering where I could get a screwdriver that will open up the 2nd generation iPhone 4.

The original iPhone 4 had normal phillips screws. The newer iPhone 4 (2nd generation, not iPhone 4S) has screws that look like a 5-pointed star.

Answer (score 7):

They are called [Pentalobe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_screw_drives#Pentalobe) screws and look similar to this picture from Wikipedia:

[image]

You can find compatible screwdrivers on [iFixit](http://www.ifixit.com/iPhone-Parts/iPhone-4#0-Screwdrivers+and+Nutdrivers) or Amazon. If you do go with Amazon, though, make sure you read the reviews before you buy anything, since many of them are filled with complaints about the product not working.

There's even a [guide](http://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Replacing-iPhone-4-5-Point-Pentalobe-Screws/4493/1) which will show you how to replace the screws with normal phillips ones.

Comment: iFixit has a kit that comes with replacement screws since it's those "pentalobe" screws are pretty fragile. Then you'll also be able to use regular philips screwdrivers after that.

Answer (score 4):

iFixit has [an article](http://www.ifixit.com/blog/2011/01/20/apples-diabolical-plan-to-screw-your-iphone/) calling these screws "Pentalobe". They also sell an "iPhone 4 Liberation Kit" which includes a driver and replacement screws that are Phillips-head.

They also mention that similar screws appear on the MacBook Pro and MacBook Air.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The name is a Pentalobe screw.

although some places call it a torx screw, [this isn't quite correct](http://guide-images.ifixit.net/igi/J2ZmCuhThPJdtneB) (Torx screw has 6 sharper points, wheras the pentalobe has 5 more rounded points, so make sure you buy a screwdriver with the correct number at least)

[Here's a screwdrive on Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0050397YM), although iFixit sell a ["Liberation Kit"](http://www.ifixit.com/iPhone-Parts/iPhone-4-Liberation-Kit/IF182-019)